# Sqoop incremental append

Tags: mysql, jdbc, import, hive, sqoop

In mysql i have mydb/emp table with fields (eid,ename,esal).

Here i have tried to import emp using incremental append in step1 without creating job and passing last-value.

```
sqoop import  -- connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB --table  test --m 1 
--target-dir /user/cloudera/mydata --incremental append --check-column eid
```

I got result with different file in mydata with name part-0001..  with updated values from eid 0 to last ex. eid 0 to eid 8 records.

But when i did same code using job, the result is diffrent...

```
sqoop job  --create dayimport  -- import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB --table  test --m 1 --target-dir /user/cloudera/mydata --incremental append --check-column eid 

sqoop job --exec dayimport
```

Here I got result with different file but only updated record i.e. from last values ex. i have updated table with new row eid 7,8 So it consist only eid 7 and 8 record.

Can somebody explain why this is happening with job not with normal script?
How to decide last value after check column if huge record? any direct way to know last updated value without checking end value?

Answer (score 0):

In the incremental import, if you dont specify the last value, sqoop import all rows, but when it's saved as job, sqoop know from where it imports even if no last value given.
You dont need to give a last value if you plan to make a saved job, but if you want to know about it, it's given in this way :

```
--last-value
```

Please see [user guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1764421).